# Reading from an array performance

Tags: c, arrays, performance, matlab, memory

In C (and higher-level languages such as Matlab), if one wants to repetitively use the (constant) value stored in an array, is it better to store it in a separate variable, i.e.:

> double array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...};
>
> double quantity = array[3];

And use `quantity` when necessary, or is it just as fast to use `array[3]`?

The reason why I ask is that `array[3] = *(array+3)` and therefore an addition operation must be performed to read from the array, whereas `quantity` can be directly read from.

Comment: Which language are you referring to? You have tagged it with both C and Matlab.

Comment: How relevant could this be by the means of performance? Not that I know much beyond branch-predictions when it comes to optimizations, but still, I'd be surprised if it made any difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most of the times the compiler will do that for you under the hood. The usual compilers are pretty smart when it comes to optimizations ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how much improvement, but when you do `a[3]`, `*(a+3)` is found by:

1. Fetch base address of a (access program counter and other registers).
2. Add the offset to this address to get address of a[3] (use ALU).
3. Then fetch value of a[3] (again access registers).

This all comes into picture when studying the architecture of a processor (like MIPS).

So, it will always be better to store variables like you have done.

Although modern compiler may support using Cache to store frequently used data rather than accessing memory each and every time.

I would like to add an example of `pow()` from `math.h`.

```
double begin = clock();
for(long long int i=0;i<pow(10,9);++i);
printf("%lf",(clock()-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

The above code might show slight performance improvement if first store `pow(10,9)`.

Comment: The address `array+3` is just as constant as the address of `quantity`… There is no need for the `+3` addition at runtime.

Comment: Then how will compiler know `array+3` without knowing knowing base address of `array` or `array+0` itself. So, I mentioned `+3 (into sizeof(variable))` here.

Comment: The compiler _does_ know the base address of `array` (usually relative to some frame pointer, though, but that's exactly the same as for the address of `quantity`, what I meant with "as constant as").